# VoiceOver focuses on aria-hidden element

Tags: html, vue.js, wai-aria, voiceover, screen-readers

On our (Vue.js v.2) webpage we have a section where you can swipe between cards, or by pressing "left" and "right" button. This swiping section is written with vanilla JS, and no fancy library. In order to have the adjacent visible when swiping, I need to have all of them visible in the DOM tree, but hiding them from the viewer. I have made it so all the unfocused cards are `aria-hidden`, and it works great when using ChromeVox. The problem is that when using VoiceOver, and I click the "right" button, and immediately tab down to the card, it will read out the card to the left, and also get trapped there since the card is aria-hidden. Code-wise the change from `aria-visible` to `aria-hidden` happens as soon as the button is pressed, but it seems like VoiceOver has already decided that when I am focusing on the "right" button, that the next element should be card 5 (for instance). If I wait around 1 or 2 seconds after clicking the "right" button, it will change the "next" element, and focus on the correct one (card 6) when I tab down. Is there any way to get around this, so it will focus only on the `aria-visible` element? Maybe a way to "force refresh" VoiceOver's stack of elements to read next? Maybe if I remove the message being read out when clicking the button, it will refresh immediately? I still haven't found of doing either of those things. [I created a low quality flowchart to illustrate the problem better](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPGzR.jpg). What I want is for it to behave like ChromeVox.

I have tried several methods of getting this to work now, and it feels like it's a bug with VoiceOver. Some of the (desperate) attempts I've tried: setting `tabindex=-1`, `role=presentation`, changing the ID of "right" button dynamically as I navigate between cards, creating an empty div with a dynamic ID below the button, using `aria-flowto`, dynamically setting `aria-describedby` on the "next" element, and different variations between these and some other stuff I can't remember.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I found a solution that kinda works. I'm not very happy about it, but it's better than nothing. What I did was to make the title inside the card `aria-hidden`, and creating a `currentHeader` variable in store. I created an `sr-only` & `aria-visible` title above the swiping section, where the `v-html` points to the `currentHeader` variable. This way, the "next" element for the "right" button will always be the same element, but content will change after I click the button. It's not a perfect solution, and for some reason it makes VoiceOver "halt" when trying to go to the next element immediately after clicking the button, but at least the user won't read the wrong text and get trapped. Here's a pseudocode illustration of how I did it if my explaination was confusing:

```
// old solution                                  // old swiping-section
<button id="left" />                             <div v-for="element in elements" />
<button id="right" />                              <h3 v-html="element.title" />
<swiping-section />                                <p v-html="element.desc" />
                                                 </div>

// new solution                                   // new swiping section
<button id="left" />                              <div v-for="element in elements" />
<button id="right" />                               <h3 aria-hidden="true" "v-html="element.title" />
<h3 class="sr-only" v-html="currentHeader" />       <p v-html="element.desc" />
<swiping-section />                               </div>
```

If anyone finds a better way to do it, please post your solution.